# Alternative initialize for a Class to avoid processing already known information

Tags: ruby, architecture, initialization, inheritance

I have a class, Autodrop, that contains several methods , a.o. 'metadata', that call an external API (dropbox). They are slow.
However, I already often have that metadata around when initializing the AutodropImage, so I should make the methods smarter.

What I have in mind is this:

```
class Autodrop
  include Dropbox
  attr_reader :path

  def initialize(path)
    @path = path
  end

  def self.from_entry(drop_entry)
    @drop_entry = drop_entry
    self.initialize(@drop_entry.path)
  end

  def metadata
    if @drop_entry = nil
      return heavy_lifting_and_network_traffic
    else
      return @drop_entry.metadata
    end
  end
  #...
end
```

Now, I would expect to call

```
entry = BarEntry.new()
foo = Autodrop.from_entry(entry)
foo.metadata
```

In order to avoid that heavy lifting and network traffic call.

But this does not work. And somehow, in all my newbieness, I am sure I am goind at this all wrong. 
Is there a term I should look for and read about first? How would you go for this?

Note, that the examples are simplified: in my code, I inherit AutodropImage < Autodrop for example, which is called from withing AutodropGallery < Autodrop. The latter already knows all metadata for the AutodropImage, so I mostly want to avoid AutodropImage going over the heavy lifting again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an instance variable `@drop_entry` in your class method `from_entry` and obviously it wont be available to your object that you are creating in this method. One workaround is to pass it as a parameter when you are initializing the class. It should work if you do the following modifications:

1. In your `from_entry` class method change

   ```
   self.initialize(@drop_entry)
   ```

   to

   ```
   new(@drop_entry)
   ```
2. Modify `initialize` method to:

   ```
   def initialize(drop_entry)
     @drop_entry = drop_entry
     @path = @drop_entry.path
   end
   ```

Or if your class is tied up to pass only the `path` parameter, ie. you dont want to change the other existing code then you can use an optional parameter drop entry like so

```
    def initialize(path, drop_entry=nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to cache the metadata in a class variable.

Edit: Or in a class level instance variable.
Maybe this read will help: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Comment: that is what I though. However, I did not mention that this is used in Sinatra. And I was told class @@variables are shared across all users/threads. But I may be misinformed there.

Comment: but you are not using class variables you are using instance variables